# Writing a web crawler using python twisted

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, twisted

I'm using `Twisted` to write a web crawler driven with `Selenium`. The idea is that I spawn twisted threads for a twisted client and a twisted server that will proxy HTTP requests to the server. Something that looks like this:

```
    +--------+       +--------+
    |        +------>+        |
 -->| Client |       | Server |---> WWW
    |        +<------+        |
    +--------+       +--------+
```

All this is running in the same process, though. The question is whether twisted allows this kind of applications or is only thought to run `Client` and `Server` as different processes (as this is the typical case I've seen everywhere).

Comment: will you share your code?

Comment: Yes, I will. I plan to release it soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Twisted in a thread.  You can, however, make a single Twisted thread which can happily make multiple clients and servers.

You may need to describe your problem in a bit more detail for a better answer than that.

Comment: Right. I didn't explained myself well. So, the main reactor would be used to run both client and server. Normally, you would have a different reactor for each because they're actually running as different processes. Then I also need to do `reactor.callInThread` to drive the browser to get the web page because otherwise I would be blocking the communication between client and server, right?

Comment: Your original question doesn't even include the word "browser".  Please edit it to clarify.

Comment: @Glyph: I edited the question to give more details. The edits should be visible once they're peer-reviewed.